# How to display column dynamically using ag-grid

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

I am new to angularjs technology.I'm using ag-grid and want to display column dynamically

---

my json data is:

```
[{Date:'12-12-2015',Name:'ammu',mark:20},{Date:'12-12-2015',Name:'appu',mark:24},{Date:'12-12-2015',Name:'anu',mark:27},{Date:'13-12-2016',Name:'ammu',mark:23},{Date:'13-12-2015',Name:'anu',mark:20}]
```

---

My Expected Output is
[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxxRd.png)

Existing Code is given below

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: [],
    enableFilter: true,
    rowData: [],
    rowSelection: 'multiple',
    rowDeselection: true
};
 $scope.customColumns = [];
Getdetails();
function Getdetails()
{
    masterdataFactory.Getdetails()
     .success(function (Student) {
        f (Student.length != 0) {
             for(var i=0;i<Student.length;i++) {
                 $scope.customColumns.push(
                     {
                         headerName: Student[i].Name,
                         field: "Mark",
                         headerClass: 'grid-halign-left'

                     }
                 );
             };
            $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = $scope.customColumns;
            $scope.gridOptions.rowData = Student;
            $scope.gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs();
          }                 
     })
      .error(function (error) {
          $scope.status = 'Unable to load data: ' + error.message;
      });
}
```

Existing Output is given below
[Existing Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGdnM.png)

How can reach my Expected Output From the existing output

Answer (score 5):

First arrange the json data

```
[{Date:'12-12-2015',ammu:20,appu:24,anu:27},{Date:'13-12-2016' ammu:23,anu:20}]
```

for this purpose i'm using following code

```
             function generateChartData() {
             var chartData = [],
               categories = {};
             for ( var i = 0; i <Student.length; i++ ) {
                 var newdate = Student[ i ].Date;
                 var Name=Student[ i ].Name;
                 var Mark=Student[ i ].Mark;
                // add new data point
                 if ( categories[ newdate ] === undefined ) {
                     categories[ newdate ] = {
                         DATE: newdate
                     };
                     chartData.push( categories[ newdate ] );
                 }

                 // add value to existing data point

                 categories[ newdate ][ Name] = Mark;
             }

             return chartData;
         }
```

grid option is given below:

```
 $scope.gridOptions = {
             columnDefs: coldef(),
             enableFilter: true,
             rowData: [],
             rowSelection: 'multiple',
             rowDeselection: true,
             enableColResize: true,

             }
           };
        $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = $scope.customColumns;
        $scope.gridOptions.rowData =generateChartData();
        $scope.gridOptions.rowData = generateChartData();
}
```

column definition is dynamic which is given below

```
  function coldef()
{
    for(var i=0;i<headers.length;i++) {
        $scope.customColumns.push(
                              {
                                  headerName: headers[i],
                                  field:headers[i],
                                  headerClass: 'grid-halign-left',
                                  width:180,
                                  filter: 'set',
                             });
        } }
```

in this header is an array . this array contain different student names

```
 var headers=new Array();
 headers[0]="DATE";
 var Names= Student.map(function (item) { return item.Name}); 
 Names= Names.filter(function (v, i) { return Names.indexOf(v) == i; }); 
         for(var i=1;i<=Names.length;i++)
         {
             headers[i]=Names[i-1];
         }
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you are using an async call to get your data so when the call suceeds the grid is already initialized.

After the grid is initialiazed you need to use the grid API (gridOptions.api...) instead of girdOptions.columnsDef (see http://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid-api/index.php)

Comment: Thank you Sebastien.i tried like this.but the result was same with TypeError:" Cannot read property 'setColumnDefs' of undefined".i didn't get my expected output.can you please help me with a solution?.My question is updated with  grid API

Comment: Basically you should use the `gridOptions.columnDefs = [...]` when grid is not yet initialized and `gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs([...])` after grid is initialized. Given your error I think the grid is not yet initialized and so gridOptions.api is still undefined when you try to call gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs(...).

Comment: Thank you  Sebastien.I got the answer

Answer (score 2):

There are quite some things wrongs in your code :

**1st** : the 'API' field is not available at start. It can means two things :

1. the grid has not YET been loaded (wrap the call in a `$timeout` or ready event check documentation on http://www.ag-grid.com).
2. You forget the ag-grid directive in your DOM element so the grid won't initialize at all.

**2nd** : don't use   `$scope.gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs();` but `$scope.gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs(myNewColumnsDefs);`

**3rd** : if the grid is already initialized don't use `rowData` use `api.setRowData(myDatas)`, probably better using it after calling `setColumnDefs` but i don't think it'll mess anything.

Comment: No problem, don't forget to validate the answer so people will know this post has been answered

Comment: 1) no, no, no!!! (how long should the timeout be???)   Use `onGridReady`

Comment: `$timeout or ready event check`. As for the how long the t$imeout is if need to be, it would be in fact a 0ms timeout, which would defer the processing to the next javascript event loop. And yes, this is not the optimal solution, but it is effectively quite stable as it doesn't rely on time but just on deferring to the next loop.

Comment: And id the grid needs a few event loops to be ready? Why use a hack when there is an `onGridyReady()` callback?

Comment: I just said that because i do remember i did sometimes use $timeout trick when dealing with angularJS. But it has been too long for me to remember if this was needed instead of onGridReady for whatever possible reason back then.

Answer (score 2):

```
// the api will not be available unless it is compiled with the **$timeout** or **setTimeout** because this javascript library does not fall in angular digest cycle
$timeout(function() {
  $scope.gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs(masterColumnDefs);
}, 0);
```

This will help you to access the API of ag-grid.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I think data your input data (Student) may be the culprit, as parenthesis seem to be weirdly paired (copied your data, but formatted to be easier to read):

```
[
    {Date:'12-12-2015',Name:'ammu',mark:20},
    Date:'12-12-2015',Name:'appu',mark:24},
    Date:'12-12-2015',Name:'anu',mark:27},
    Date:'13-12-2016',Name:'ammu',mark:23},
    {Date:'13-12-2015',Name:'anu',mark:20}
]
```

The second, third and fourth line do not have a beginning `{`.

Comment: sorry. Its my fault,the format of json is wrong. i updated my json data.     But actually it is not the problem.can you please help me with a solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $scope.gridOptions ={
        enableSorting: true,
        enableFilter: true,
        suppressMovableColumns:true,
        enableColResize: true,
        columnDefs : [],
        rowHeight : 27,
        tooltipField : true,
        suppressLoadingOverlay : true,
        overlayLoadingTemplate: '<span class="ag-overlay-loading-center" style=background:lightgoldenrodyellow>Please wait while your rows are loading</span>',
        //getRowStyle : getRowStyleScheduled
    };       

    $scope.gridRefresh = function() { 
$scope.columnsHeaders =[];
        for (var i = 0, len = $scope.columnsHeaders.length; i < len; i++) {
            $scope.columnsHeaders[i].headerName = $scope.columnsHeaders[i].name;
            $scope.columnsHeaders[i].field = $scope.columnsHeaders[i].field;
            $scope.columnsHeaders[i].cellRenderer = function(params) {
                if(params.value != null) {
                    return '<span title="'+params.value+'">'+params.value+'</span>';
                }else {
                    return null;
                }
            }
         $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs.push($scope.columnsHeaders[i]);
        }
        $scope.gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs($scope.gridOptions.columnDefs);
        $scope.gridOptions.api.setRowData($scope.Rows);
        $scope.gridOptions.columnApi.autoSizeColumns($scope.gridOptions.columnDefs);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for same thing in angular 6. But this page came out in google. I am providing answer in angular 6 in case if somebody wants to derive column definitions from a rest API,

I am using size columns to fit since columns are dynamic so that they fits to available grid width

```
ngOnInit() {
this.gridOptions = {
  onGridSizeChanged: () => {
    this.gridApi.sizeColumnsToFit();
  },
  onNewColumnsLoaded: () => {
    if (this.gridApi) {
      this.gridApi.sizeColumnsToFit();
    }
  },
  defaultColDef: {
    width: 150,
    minWidth: 100,
    maxWidth: 400
  }
};
this.getcolumnData();
```

}

```
getcolumnData() {
this.pageType =  this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('type');
this.http.get(`${this.baseURL}/getStaticMetaData`).subscribe(res => {
  let columnDef = [];
  res.forEach(column => {
    columnDef = [...columnDef, {headerName: column.columnName, field: column.columnId}];
  });
  this.gridApi.setColumnDefs(columnDef);
});
```

}

```
onGridReady(params) {
this.gridApi = params.api;
this.http.get(`${this.baseURL}/getStaticData`).subscribe(data => {
  if (data.length < 20) {
    this.isSmallGrid = true;
  }
  this.gridApi.setRowData(data);
}, err => {
  // handle error
});
```

}

```
<ag-grid-angular style="width: 100%;" 
  [ngStyle]="{'height.px': isSmallGrid ? '325' : '725'}"
  class="ag-theme-balham"
  [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
  (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
  enableColResize enableSorting enableFilter
  >
  </ag-grid-angular>
```